# wp_rewrite not working on third level url

Tags: customization, url-rewriting

I have the following code :

```
global $wp;
        $wp->add_query_var('akey');
        $wp->add_query_var('sort');
        $wp->add_query_var('paged');
        add_rewrite_rule('^activate/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=activate&akey=$matches[1]','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/$','index.php?pagename=users','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/most-active/?','index.php?pagename=users&sort=mostactive','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/most-active/paged/([^/]*)/$','index.php?pagename=users&sort=mostactive&paged=$matches[1]','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/recent/?','index.php?pagename=users&sort=recent','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/recent/paged/([^/]*)/$','index.php?pagename=users&sort=recent&paged=$matches[1]','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/oldest/?','index.php?pagename=users&sort=oldest','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/oldest/paged/([^/]*)/$','index.php?pagename=users&sort=oldest&paged=$matches[1]','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/by-username/?','index.php?pagename=users&sort=byusername','top');
        add_rewrite_rule('^users/by-username/paged/([^/]*)/$','index.php?pagename=users&sort=byusername&paged=$matches[1]','top');
```

the problem is the following users/recent/ works while users/recent/paged/number/ does not work

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is a little flaky - you shouldn't specify the start anchor `^`, and some support trailing slashes, others don't - plus I'd opt for a better expression for matching page numbers. And you could certainly trim it down to:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'activate/([^/]*)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=activate&akey=$matches[1]','top' );

add_rewrite_rule(
    'users/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=users','top' );

add_rewrite_rule(
    'users/(most-active|recent|oldest|by-username)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=users&sort=$matches[1]','top' );

add_rewrite_rule(
    'users/(most-active|recent|oldest|by-username)/paged/([0-9]{1,})/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=users&sort=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top' );
```

I noticed that `by-username` translates to the sort parameter `byusername` - if the sorting logic can't be changed to accept the hyphenated value (which I recommend for consistency), add a separate, specific rule-pair.

If you're still having problems, load the request and print out `$wp->matched_rule` - this'll tell you which rule WordPress hit & proceeded to handle.

Comment: Your answer is great however I have the following problem the script works until you reach paged/2 form paged/2 it adds something like : users/recent/paged/4/page/4/ I don't know where the page/4 comes from

Comment: Have you flushed your rules? I know you're adding them on-the-fly but it's always worth ruling out (just visit the permalinks settings page to flush).

Comment: I have done that but still no luck ..

Comment: What was the result of `$wp->matched_rule`?